# Any statements in Vedas and the principal Upanishads that deny Vishnu as God?

Tags: vedas, vishnu, upanishads

Any statements in the Vedas and in the upanishads limited to only principal upanishads that deny Vishnu being God.

I am looking for specific statements for eg: like [this](https://www.upanishads.iitk.ac.in/taittiriya?language=dv&field_chap_value=2&field_sec_value=8&field_mantra_no_value=1&etgb=1) one for Indra:

> Out of His fear the Wind blows. Out of fear the Sun rises. Out of His
>   fear runs Fire, as also Indra, and Death, the fifth.

I am not looking for statements which say other god is supreme.

Answer (score 3):

Rig veda 9.96.5 talks of the birth of Vishnu -

> सोमः पवते जनिता मतीनां जनिता दिवो जनिता पर्थिव्याः |
>   जनिताग्नेर्जनिता सूर्यस्य जनितेन्द्रस्य जनितोत विष्णोः ||

Translation by Griffith [here](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rigveda/rv09096.htm)

> Father of holy hymns, Soma flows onward the Father of the earth, Father of heaven:
>   Father of Agni, Sūrya's generator, the Father who begat Indra and Viṣṇu.

Since brahman has no birth, this verse is as good as denying that Vishnu is God (unless it is forcibly interpreted as referring to an incarnation).

Comment: @i will close your question - I don't think that is the best translation for RV 9.96.5 . The verse , which is about Soma, seems to be better explained here https://books.google.co.in/books?id=2rvQCgAAQBAJ&pg=PT282&lpg=PT282&dq=Soma%20is%20bliss%20or%20Ananda%20david%20frawley&source=bl&ots=ruAvRQIFfP&sig=ACfU3U1BVUh4uLUyj0bSc_i1ZivdNwgF8A&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjMnMXemvbkAhVDiXAKHZBJDvgQ6AEwCHoECAcQAQ#v=onepage&q=Soma%20is%20bliss%20or%20Ananda%20david%20frawley&f=false

Comment: @Carmen How is the word Vishnu being interpreted in your reference?

Comment: Soma is the bliss that serves as inspiration to Rishis, and thua propel them to beget Vishnu like powers